# Running a python script on start-up/background in Ubuntu Linux - Failed to start service, Unit Not Found

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, configuration, upstart

I wrote a python script and need this to be running 24/7. Haven't really done this before and I decided to use upstart in my Digital Ocean cloud running Ubuntu, and followed the below tutorial.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/the-upstart-event-system-what-it-is-and-how-to-use-it

Below is my conf file pdlb.conf located in /etc/init

```
description "A basic bot to get fixture information"
author "abcuser"

start on runlevel [2345]
exec python3 /home/abcuser/bot/pdlb.py >> /var/log/pdlb.log
```

**I checked the syntax using init-checkconf and it showed syntaxOK**

On running this (sudo service pdlb start), I got the following error and I don't know how to fix it. The pdlb.py file is in the correct location and log file isn't created yet.

```
Failed to start pdlb.service: Unit pdlb.service not found.
```

Do you have idea where I went wrong with this process? Any help will be appreciated, thanks.